# Tomcat8 doesn't detect Letsencrypt renewed certificate (but Apache does)

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, tomcat, lets-encrypt, tomcat8

I have an Ubuntu 17.10 Server with Apache 2.4.27 and Tomcat 8.5.21, both serving through HTTPS thanks to a Letsencrypt Certificate. It's been working fine for 3 months and automatic renewal (with default `cron`) worked. But after the original expiration date, my Apache is still working fine using the renewed certificate, but Tomcat8 is still using the expired certificate, so I get the *Insecure Connection* warning on my browser.

I tried `force-reload` on my Tomcat8 service and even rebooting the whole server without success.

This is my Tomcat8 configuration for SSL on `server.xml`:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"
    sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" keyAlias="tomcat"
    keystoreType="JKS"
    keystoreFile="/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/MyDSKeyStore.jks"
    keystorePass="PASSWORD" />
```

If I try:

```
openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -showcerts
```

I see my Apache, effectively using the renewed certificate, but for Tomcat8, on port 8443:

```
openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8443 -showcerts
```

> [...] verify error:num=10:certificate has expired [...]

Any idea on how can I make my Tomcat use the renewed certificate?

**Update:**

Thanks to comments, I've seen that the Tomcat keystore on `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/MyDSKeyStore.jks` was not touched by the renewal. So I guess the real problem here is how to automatically update this file when my certificate renews.

Comment: what is the timestamp of `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/MyDSKeyStore.jks`? Are you sure that this file is supposed to be updated by the standard Let's Encrypt renewal script?

Comment: You're right @AlexD timestamp on the file is the date of creation, not the day the renewal took place... I'll make a search on how to update this file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Standard Let's Encrypt `certbot` doesn't support JKS key store format, so your `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/MyDSKeyStore.jks` file was created manually and needs to be updated after each renewal. You can try using `certbot renew --deploy-hook` to do this, check [its documentation](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#renewing-certificates) for details.

Comment: You're right. I remember creating the `jks`... I'll take a look at the docs you linked to automatize this process.